# obexftp -l fails, return code 81

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, obex, obexftp

I am currently attempting to use obex tools to browse (and later mount) the file system of an Android device (7.1.1). When I try to list using obexftp -l, it simply returns nothing.  I have tried almost every possible combination of file parameters after -l, but still get the same error. My end goal is to use obexfs to mount, but feel this is an intermediate stepping stone. Details below.

```
uname -r:  3.14.2-xilinx

bluetoothd -v:  4.101

bluetoothctl -v  5.47

lsusb:  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0

hcitool dev:  hci0      5C:F3:70:82:XX:XX

hciconfig -a:
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 5C:F3:70:82:XX:XX  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN
    RX bytes:13146 acl:211 sco:0 events:382 errors:0
    TX bytes:6265 acl:219 sco:0 commands:149 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
    Name: '312_BT-0'
    Class: 0x000100
    Service Classes: Unspecified
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1000
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x220e
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

**Succesful file push from Linux device to Android device:**

```
obexftp -b D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX -B 6 -U none -p /home/root/test.txt
Suppressing FBS.
Connecting..\done
Sending "/home/root/test.txt".../done
Disconnecting..-done
```

**Attempting to list file structure on Android device:**

```
obexftp -b D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX -B 6 -U none -l
Suppressing FBS.
Connecting..\done
Receiving "(null)"...|failed: (null)
The operation failed with return code 81
Disconnecting../done
```

**Output of btmon when attempting above obexftp -l command:**

```
= New Index: 5C:F3:70:82:XX:XX (Primary,USB,hci0)             [hci0] 0.316536
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13          #1 [hci0] 3.563946
    Address: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (OUI D4-63-C6)
    Packet type: 0xcc18
      DM1 may be used
      DH1 may be used
      DM3 may be used
      DH3 may be used
      DM5 may be used
      DH5 may be used
    Page scan repetition mode: R2 (0x02)
    Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
    Clock offset: 0x0000
    Role switch: Allow slave (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4           #2 [hci0] 3.565628
  Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Role Change (0x12) plen 8           #3 [hci0] 5.392513
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Address: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (OUI D4-63-C6)
    Role: Slave (0x01)
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11           #4 [hci0] 5.414518
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 11
    Address: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (OUI D4-63-C6)
    Link type: ACL (0x01)
    Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
< HCI Command: Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) plen 2          #5 [hci0] 5.414709
    Handle: 11
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4           #6 [hci0] 5.415523
  Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3           #7 [hci0] 5.425523
    Handle: 11
    Max slots: 5
> HCI Event: Link Supervision Timeout Changed (0x38) plen 4           #8 [hci0] 5.429522
    Handle: 11
    Timeout: 5000.000 msec (0x1f40)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 10           #9 [hci0] 5.432524
  L2CAP: Information Request (0x0a) ident 2 len 2
    Type: Extended features supported (0x0002)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 16         #10 [hci0] 5.432580
  L2CAP: Information Response (0x0b) ident 2 len 8
    Type: Extended features supported (0x0002)
    Result: Success (0x0000)
    Features: 0x000002b8
      Enhanced Retransmission Mode
      Streaming Mode
      FCS Option
      Fixed Channels
      Unicast Connectionless Data Reception
> HCI Event: Read Remote Supported Features (0x0b) plen 11          #11 [hci0] 5.438528
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 11
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
      3 slot packets
      5 slot packets
      Encryption
      Slot offset
      Timing accuracy
      Role switch
      Hold mode
      Sniff mode
      Power control requests
      Channel quality driven data rate (CQDDR)
      SCO link
      HV2 packets
      HV3 packets
      u-law log synchronous data
      A-law log synchronous data
      CVSD synchronous data
      Paging parameter negotiation
      Power control
      Transparent synchronous data
      Broadcast Encryption
      Enhanced Data Rate ACL 2 Mbps mode
      Enhanced Data Rate ACL 3 Mbps mode
      Enhanced inquiry scan
      Interlaced inquiry scan
      Interlaced page scan
      RSSI with inquiry results
      Extended SCO link (EV3 packets)
      AFH capable slave
      AFH classification slave
      LE Supported (Controller)
      3-slot Enhanced Data Rate ACL packets
      5-slot Enhanced Data Rate ACL packets
      Sniff subrating
      Pause encryption
      AFH capable master
      AFH classification master
      Enhanced Data Rate eSCO 2 Mbps mode
      Extended Inquiry Response
      Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR (Controller)
      Secure Simple Pairing
      Encapsulated PDU
      Non-flushable Packet Boundary Flag
      Link Supervision Timeout Changed Event
      Inquiry TX Power Level
      Enhanced Power Control
      Extended features
< HCI Command: Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) plen 3         #12 [hci0] 5.438569
    Handle: 11
    Page: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 10          #13 [hci0] 5.438782
  L2CAP: Information Request (0x0a) ident 3 len 2
    Type: Fixed channels supported (0x0003)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 20         #14 [hci0] 5.438818
  L2CAP: Information Response (0x0b) ident 3 len 12
    Type: Fixed channels supported (0x0003)
    Result: Success (0x0000)
    Channels: 0x0000000000000006
      L2CAP Signaling (BR/EDR)
      Connectionless reception
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4          #15 [hci0] 5.440527
  Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #16 [hci0] 5.443529
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> HCI Event: Read Remote Extended Features (0x23) plen 13          #17 [hci0] 5.444528
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 11
    Page: 1/1
    Features: 0x0f 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
      Secure Simple Pairing (Host Support)
      LE Supported (Host)
      Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR (Host)
      Secure Connections (Host Support)
< HCI Command: Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) plen 10         #18 [hci0] 5.444573
    Address: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (OUI D4-63-C6)
    Page scan repetition mode: R2 (0x02)
    Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
    Clock offset: 0x0000
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4          #19 [hci0] 5.445529
  Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Remote Name Req Complete (0x07) plen 255          #20 [hci0] 5.465535
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Address: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (OUI D4-63-C6)
    Name: Moto E (4)
< HCI Command: Authentication Requested (0x01|0x0011) plen 2         #21 [hci0] 5.465591
    Handle: 11
Device Connected: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (0) flags 0x0000
    0b 09 4d 6f 74 6f 20 45 20 28 34 29 04 0d 0c 02  ..Moto E (4)....
    5a                                               Z
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4          #22 [hci0] 5.466545
  Authentication Requested (0x01|0x0011) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Link Key Request (0x17) plen 6          #23 [hci0] 5.467541
    Address: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (OUI D4-63-C6)
< HCI Command: Link Key Request Reply (0x01|0x000b) plen 22         #24 [hci0] 5.467588
    Address: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (OUI D4-63-C6)
    Link key: b0912a0c42db7615860023aa911d552b
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10          #25 [hci0] 5.470540
  Link Key Request Reply (0x01|0x000b) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Address: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (OUI D4-63-C6)
> HCI Event: Auth Complete (0x06) plen 3          #26 [hci0] 5.489555
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 11
< HCI Command: Set Connection Encryption (0x01|0x0013) plen 3         #27 [hci0] 5.489604
    Handle: 11
    Encryption: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4          #28 [hci0] 5.490550
  Set Connection Encryption (0x01|0x0013) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Encryption Change (0x08) plen 4          #29 [hci0] 5.532580
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 11
    Encryption: Enabled with E0 (0x01)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 10         #30 [hci0] 5.532645
  L2CAP: Information Request (0x0a) ident 1 len 2
    Type: Extended features supported (0x0002)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 16          #31 [hci0] 5.562719
  L2CAP: Information Response (0x0b) ident 1 len 8
    Type: Extended features supported (0x0002)
    Result: Success (0x0000)
    Features: 0x000000b8
      Enhanced Retransmission Mode
      Streaming Mode
      FCS Option
      Fixed Channels
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 10         #32 [hci0] 5.562780
  L2CAP: Information Request (0x0a) ident 2 len 2
    Type: Fixed channels supported (0x0003)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #33 [hci0] 5.565591
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 20          #34 [hci0] 5.566462
  L2CAP: Information Response (0x0b) ident 2 len 12
    Type: Fixed channels supported (0x0003)
    Result: Success (0x0000)
    Channels: 0x0000000000000082
      L2CAP Signaling (BR/EDR)
      Security Manager (BR/EDR)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 12         #35 [hci0] 5.566511
  L2CAP: Connection Request (0x02) ident 3 len 4
    PSM: 3 (0x0003)
    Source CID: 64
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 16          #36 [hci0] 5.570089
  L2CAP: Connection Response (0x03) ident 3 len 8
    Destination CID: 67
    Source CID: 64
    Result: Connection successful (0x0000)
    Status: No further information available (0x0000)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 27         #37 [hci0] 5.570138
  L2CAP: Configure Request (0x04) ident 4 len 19
    Destination CID: 67
    Flags: 0x0000
    Option: Maximum Transmission Unit (0x01) [mandatory]
      MTU: 1013
    Option: Retransmission and Flow Control (0x04) [mandatory]
      Mode: Basic (0x00)
      TX window size: 0
      Max transmit: 0
      Retransmission timeout: 0
      Monitor timeout: 0
      Maximum PDU size: 0
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 16          #38 [hci0] 5.571470
  L2CAP: Configure Request (0x04) ident 4 len 8
    Destination CID: 64
    Flags: 0x0000
    Option: Maximum Transmission Unit (0x01) [mandatory]
      MTU: 1691
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 18         #39 [hci0] 5.571521
  L2CAP: Configure Response (0x05) ident 4 len 10
    Source CID: 67
    Flags: 0x0000
    Result: Success (0x0000)
    Option: Maximum Transmission Unit (0x01) [mandatory]
      MTU: 1691
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #40 [hci0] 5.573594
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 14          #41 [hci0] 5.573967
  L2CAP: Configure Response (0x05) ident 4 len 6
    Source CID: 64
    Flags: 0x0000
    Result: Success (0x0000)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 8         #42 [hci0] 5.574064
  Channel: 67 len 4 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Set Async Balance Mode (SABM) (0x2f)
     Address: 0x03 cr 1 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0x3f poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0x1c
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #43 [hci0] 5.577595
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 8          #44 [hci0] 5.577612
  Channel: 64 len 4 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Ack (UA) (0x63)
     Address: 0x03 cr 1 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0x73 poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0xd7
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 18         #45 [hci0] 5.577681
  Channel: 67 len 14 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x03 cr 1 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 10
     FCS: 0x70
     MCC Message type: DLC Parameter Negotiation CMD (0x20)
       Length: 8
       dlci 12 frame_type 0 credit_flow 15 pri 7
       ack_timer 0 frame_size 1008 max_retrans 0 credits 7
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 18          #46 [hci0] 5.581473
  Channel: 64 len 14 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x01 cr 0 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 10
     FCS: 0xaa
     MCC Message type: DLC Parameter Negotiation RSP (0x20)
       Length: 8
       dlci 12 frame_type 0 credit_flow 14 pri 7
       ack_timer 0 frame_size 990 max_retrans 0 credits 7
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 8         #47 [hci0] 5.581541
  Channel: 67 len 4 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Set Async Balance Mode (SABM) (0x2f)
     Address: 0x33 cr 1 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0x3f poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0x43
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #48 [hci0] 5.584597
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 8          #49 [hci0] 5.585096
  Channel: 64 len 4 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Ack (UA) (0x63)
     Address: 0x33 cr 1 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0x73 poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0x88
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 12         #50 [hci0] 5.585552
  Channel: 67 len 8 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x03 cr 1 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 4
     FCS: 0x70
     MCC Message type: Modem Status Command CMD (0x38)
       Length: 2
       dlci 12
       fc 0 rtc 1 rtr 1 ic 0 dv 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 12          #51 [hci0] 5.591479
  Channel: 64 len 8 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x01 cr 0 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 4
     FCS: 0xaa
     MCC Message type: Modem Status Command RSP (0x38)
       Length: 2
       dlci 12
       fc 0 rtc 1 rtr 1 ic 0 dv 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 12          #52 [hci0] 5.592601
  Channel: 64 len 8 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x01 cr 0 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 4
     FCS: 0xaa
     MCC Message type: Modem Status Command CMD (0x38)
       Length: 2
       dlci 12
       fc 0 rtc 1 rtr 1 ic 0 dv 1
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 12         #53 [hci0] 5.592664
  Channel: 67 len 8 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x03 cr 1 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 4
     FCS: 0x70
     MCC Message type: Modem Status Command RSP (0x38)
       Length: 2
       dlci 12
       fc 0 rtc 1 rtr 1 ic 0 dv 1
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 9         #54 [hci0] 5.592678
  Channel: 67 len 5 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x33 cr 1 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0xff poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0x53
     Credits: 33
    53                                               S
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 15         #55 [hci0] 5.592688
  Channel: 67 len 11 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x33 cr 1 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 7
     FCS: 0x4f
    80 00 07 10 00 04 00 4f                          .......O
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #56 [hci0] 5.595604
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #57 [hci0] 5.598602
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 21          #58 [hci0] 5.601479
  Channel: 64 len 17 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x31 cr 0 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0xff poll/final 1
     Length: 12
     FCS: 0x89
     Credits: 4
    a0 00 0c 10 00 04 00 cb 00 00 00 01 89           .............
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 41         #59 [hci0] 5.601739
  Channel: 67 len 37 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x33 cr 1 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 33
     FCS: 0x4f
    83 00 21 cb 00 00 00 01 42 00 19 78 2d 6f 62 65  ..!.....B..x-obe
    78 2f 66 6f 6c 64 65 72 2d 6c 69 73 74 69 6e 67  x/folder-listing
    00 4f                                            .O
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 17          #60 [hci0] 5.612611
  Channel: 64 len 13 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x31 cr 0 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0xff poll/final 1
     Length: 8
     FCS: 0x89
     Credits: 1
    d1 00 08 cb 00 00 00 01 89                       .........
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 16         #61 [hci0] 5.613075
  Channel: 67 len 12 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x33 cr 1 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0xef poll/final 0
     Length: 8
     FCS: 0x4f
    81 00 08 cb 00 00 00 01 4f                       ........O
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #62 [hci0] 5.618623
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 17          #63 [hci0] 5.623869
  Channel: 64 len 13 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Info with Header Check (UIH) (0xef)
     Address: 0x31 cr 0 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0xff poll/final 1
     Length: 8
     FCS: 0x89
     Credits: 1
    a0 00 08 cb 00 00 00 01 89                       .........
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 8         #64 [hci0] 5.624057
  Channel: 67 len 4 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Disconnect (DISC) (0x43)
     Address: 0x33 cr 1 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0x53 poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0xa2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 8          #65 [hci0] 5.628872
  Channel: 64 len 4 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Ack (UA) (0x63)
     Address: 0x33 cr 1 dlci 0x0c
     Control: 0x73 poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0x88
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 8         #66 [hci0] 5.628967
  Channel: 67 len 4 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Disconnect (DISC) (0x43)
     Address: 0x03 cr 1 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0x53 poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0xfd
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #67 [hci0] 5.632625
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 8          #68 [hci0] 5.632644
  Channel: 64 len 4 [PSM 3 mode 0] {chan 0}
  RFCOMM: Unnumbered Ack (UA) (0x63)
     Address: 0x03 cr 1 dlci 0x00
     Control: 0x73 poll/final 1
     Length: 0
     FCS: 0xd7
< ACL Data TX: Handle 11 flags 0x00 dlen 12         #69 [hci0] 5.632733
  L2CAP: Disconnection Request (0x06) ident 5 len 4
    Destination CID: 67
    Source CID: 64
> ACL Data RX: Handle 11 flags 0x02 dlen 12          #70 [hci0] 5.637623
  L2CAP: Disconnection Response (0x07) ident 5 len 4
    Destination CID: 67
    Source CID: 64
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          #71 [hci0] 5.863739
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 11
    Count: 1
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3         #72 [hci0] 7.631380
    Handle: 11
    Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4          #73 [hci0] 7.632590
  Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4          #74 [hci0] 7.727640
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 11
    Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
Device Disconnected: D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX (0) reason 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to try many different things, I realized that is was more than likely the Android device having the issue. The solution is that the Android device needs to have an FTP Service running in order to utilize obexftp -l or obexfs.  I achieved this by installing ES File Explorer on the Android device and selecting 'bluetooth' under the 'Network' tab.  This opens an Obex FTP path on Bluetooth channel 20.  The code below now functions; as well as obexfs.

```
obexftp -b D4:63:C6:XX:XX:XX -B 20 -U none -l
```